# What are Insurance Reserves on The Balance Sheet

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, accounting, balance-sheet

Are insurance reserves JUST the amount the company expects (the max) amount it may have to pay in the future for claims.
Or  (B) is it the cash or cash equivalent the company set aside for possible insurance claims?
If (B) why is it under Current Liabilites if the company set aside the money.(Since this “set aside cash” is not under cash and cash equivalents as opposed to debt, where the cash is under “cash and cash equivalents “ AND then the debt is under “current liabilites” Though by investment reserves it was never counted as current cash as it is set aside, so why should it be conted as a liability)
P.S the company I am looking at is Lyft

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the answer in the [S-1](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1759509/000119312519059849/d633517ds1.htm)

> Insurance Reserves

> We utilize both a wholly-owned insurance subsidiary and third-party insurance, which may include deductibles and self-insured retentions, to insure or reinsure costs, including auto liability, uninsured and underinsured motorist, auto physical damage and general business liabilities up to certain limits. The recorded liabilities reflect the estimated ultimate cost for claims incurred but not paid and claims that have been incurred but not yet reported and any estimable administrative run-out expenses related to the processing of these outstanding claim payments. Liabilities are evaluated for appropriateness with claims reserve valuations provided by an independent third-party actuary. To limit exposure to some risks, we maintain additional insurance coverage with varying limits and retentions. We cannot predict whether this insurance will be adequate to cover all potential hazards incidental to our business.

> Liability insurance claims may take several years to completely settle, and we have limited historical loss experience. Because of the limited operational history, we make certain assumptions based on currently available information and industry statistics and utilize actuarial models and techniques to estimate the reserves. A number of factors can affect the actual cost of a claim, including the length of time the claim remains open, economic and healthcare cost trends and the results of related litigation. Furthermore, claims may emerge in future years for events that occurred in a prior year at a rate that differs from previous actuarial projections. Accordingly, actual losses may vary significantly from the estimated amounts reported in the consolidated financial statements. Reserves are continually reviewed and adjusted as necessary as experience develops or new information becomes known. However, ultimate results may differ from our estimates, which could result in losses over our reserved amounts. Such adjustments are recorded in cost of revenue or general and administrative expenses depending on the nature of the reserves.